# What is the quickest way to serialize a Java object to Map (and parse back) with minimum code writing?

Tags: java, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a system that entities (from database, represented as Java objects through ORM) will be read by XML-RPC clients, my existing way is to serialize them via a `StructSerializer`, which in its code, we read properties out from the Java object, including calling another `StructSerializer` to serialize/parse a property, e.g.

```
Surrogate parse(Map<String, Object> in) {
  String name = in.get(Surrogate.NAME, String.class);
  ...
}

Map<String, Object> serialize(Surrogate in) {
  out.put(Surrogate.ID, in.getId());
  out.put(Surrogate.USER, userSerializer.serialize(in.getUser()))
}
```

What I am looking now is to eliminate/automate/minimize writing such code. Also, XML-RPC-compatible is not really the issue.

Thanks a lot.

*Edited:*

To elaborate further, XML conversion is handled by Apache XML-RPC, all I need is to dump in a Map for it to work on. What I need now is a unified/well-accepted way to convert Java objects to Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I refined my search and found: [How to convert a Java object (bean) to key-value pairs (and vice versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739689/how-to-convert-a-java-object-bean-to-key-value-pairs-and-vice-versa)

That suggests BeanUtils as a good solution.

Comment: is it even legal here. posting question and answer it yourself. That too not a real answer, just a redirection.

Comment: @Barun what's a *real* answer?

Comment: @Barun Yes, OP can answer their own question , please visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

I like XStream for this kind of work - http://x-stream.github.io/

All you have to do is annotate your classes and feed them into the XStream serializer/deserializer. You may want to annotate specific fields to tune the output, but you usually don't have to.

Comment: Can XStream convert them to Map, rather than XML?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to be compatible, there are a number of options: [XMLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html), [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), [Castor](http://www.castor.org/xml-framework.html). They all require very little code to write, unless you need something fancy. XMLEncoder is included in the JRE, others are additional libraries.

Comment: Can XStream/Castor/etc convert them to Map, rather than XML?

Comment: No, I don't think they can, sorry. Didn't understand you need a Map from the original question

Comment: I think those URLs are out of date