# Flattening an object graph to a map

Tags: java

I'm trying to flatten an object graph completely to a map.

Complex objects should also be flattened to the top level using "namespaces". So if the object A contains an int i, a string pid and another object B that contains a string id, the resulting Map would look like {i=1, pid="test", B.id="test1"}.

I also want to be able to reconstruct the original object from a given map.

I've searched around for libraries that do this. But I'm not quite getting what I'm looking for. I see stuff that maintains the hierarchy but nothing that completely flattens the structure.

I do see something in Spring Integration that looks like what I want to do: 
http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/transformer/ObjectToMapTransformer.html#ObjectToMapTransformer%28%29

But I can't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the graph a DAG (Directed, acyclic i.e. tree-like?) or can it happen that A has an object B that has an object that is A again. In that case, how do you handle references without risking that the map grows to infinity for two objects that refer to eachother?

Comment: I'm working with the assumption that there are no cycles in the object graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache BeanUtils library has a describe() method that does something similar to what I was looking for.

Another possible solution would be via the Jackson JSON library, since JSON objects are essentially key-value pairs.

Related discussions: [How to convert a Java object (bean) to key-value pairs (and vice versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739689/how-to-convert-a-java-object-bean-to-key-value-pairs-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Protobufs](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html)?

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I'd prefer not to introduce a new data format into the application.

Answer (score 0):

The [json-flattener](https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener) library solves exactly your problem