# Bean that implements Map in my JSP doesn't call getters

Tags: java, jsp

I've made some custom beans that implement the Map interface for easy access to arbitrary data in my JSP.

Example:

```
${person["cellPhoneNumber"]}
```

This extra data may or may not be added on the back end so a Map seems like a nice flexible way to store this.

The problem arises when I try to use the getters on my bean. My Person class has a `getName()` method. When using the following in my JSP, the `Map.get()` method is called instead of my method.

```
${person.name}
```

Is there a way to get around this call to Map's `get("name")` and call `getName()` instead?

Here is my basic (stripped down) Java class:

```
class Person implements Map
{
    private HashMap<String, Object> myMap;
    private String name;
    public Object get(Object key)
    {
        return myMap.get(key);
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Using JSTL 1.1

Comment: I think your problem is a bad design decision.  Your object fails the IS-A Map test.  Don't implement that interface, no matter how "convenient" you think it is.  It's a bad abstraction.

Comment: @duffymo Do you mean that it fails the IS-A Map because I haven't implemented all the methods or is it something else? I only posted the relevant parts of the class as an example to keep it brief.

Comment: No, it's not true that Person IS-A Map.  Don't implement that interface.  If your Person is a Java Bean it'll work fine in the JSP.

Comment: I guess because I'm saying that Person IS-A Map, JSP wants to treat it as a Map only. Is it instead possible to have JSP treat my object as a Bean first, Map second?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like servlet container treats every class implementing `Map` interface as a map and completely discards other methods, falling back to by key lookup. I see two solutions:

1) `get(Object key)` should be aware of normal properties:

```
class Person implements Map
{
    private HashMap<String, Object> myMap;
    private String name;
    public Object get(Object key)
    {
        switch(key) {
            case "name": return getName();
            default: myMap.get(key)
        }
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

This is a bit clumsy and not very scalable. Also it's probably easier to either use reflection and find all fields automatically or convert your bean to map (see: [How to convert a Java object (bean) to key-value pairs (and vice versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739689)). Even worse.

2) Expose your map as a special bean attribute:

```
class Person
{
    private HashMap<String, Object> optional;
    private String name;
    public Map<String, Object> getOptional()
    {
        return optional;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Then your EL expression looks like this:

```
${person.optional['cellPhoneNumber']}
```

This is a much better approach since:

- it's faster and more scalable
- better represents your intent
- it's a better design (as highlighted by *duffymo* in comments) - `Person` *has* optional attributes like cell phone number. `Person` *is not* a ``Map` of optional attributes.

Comment: I agree, nice explaination. I will probably fall back to your way of using the optional map data. I was just surprised when none of my bean accessors were getting called after I implemented Map.