# Library to translate a java bean to a map

Tags: java, android, javabeans

It is for Android, I know beanutils can do that but it doesn't work on Android.

Assume I have an java bean

```
class A
{
private int a;
public int getA() {
return a;
}
public int setA(int a) {
this.a = a;
}
}
```

what I want is:

```
A a= new A();
a.setA(1);

Map<string, object> m = somelibrary.translate(a);
```

and I'd like that `m` contains one key-value pair `{"a", 1}`

Comment: You could write one, using reflection.  But Android doesn't use beans really.  Why do you want to use one?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12902658/180100)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the answer, but can you explain to me why you need something like this?

Comment: BTW I just realized that Dozer can do it. You can check if it works on Android.

Comment: the reason i want this is: i am using RestTemplate as a rest client and i need FormHttpMessageConverter to post data to the service but it requires a map other than an object as parameter. so i want a easy way to translate an object to a map. @e