# common and generic html thyemleaf datatable page spring-boot java

Tags: java, spring-boot, datatables, thymeleaf, generic-programming

I have more than 300 controllers. I would like to have one and only one HTML page for all controllers.

I know to make loop over a list like this in thyeleaf.

```html
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="client : ${customerList}">
        <td th:text="${client.getClientID()}"></td>
        <td th:text="${client.getIpAddress()}"></td>
        <td th:text="${client.getDescription()}"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But how to iterate over any list without specifying properties like `clientID` or `ipAddress` or description?
And be able to do something like this with generic operation:

```html
<td><a th:href="'/delete/' + ${client.getClientID}">Delete</a></td>
<td><a th:href="'/edit/' + ${client.getClientID}">Edit</a></td>
```

hope to be clear

Please see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctUsr.png).

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to specify `getClientID()`, `getIpAddress()` at all for just looping through the list.

```
<tr th:each="client : ${customerList}">
    <td>Repeat me</td>
</tr>
```

If you use the above loop you will get `<td>Repeat me</td>` as many times as the size of the list `customerList`.

Comment: The op definitely needs to show the data from the list,

Comment: Yeah generally everybody does. But i guess @Juliette wants something else. Or atleast thats what i understood from her question. :)

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do it!!

Comment: Check my answer, if you can change how you add your data in model, it works.

Comment: Thanks Isah and Abdullah, i will try this night and tel you later

Comment: @Juliette- You have not accepted an answer to any of your questions. Consider accepting an answer if it has solved your problem. Check out [how accepting an answer works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in your model as `List<Map<String, String>>` where every object of the list is represented as a `map`, `map`'s key is object attribute name, and `value` is object's attribute value.

Then on your view, this will do:

```
<table th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(listOfMaps)}">
   <thead>
      <!--Columns detection/display -->
      <th th:each="firstObjEntry: ${listOfMaps[0]}" th:text="${firstObjEntry['key']}">
      </th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr th:each="objMap: ${listOfMaps}">
         <td th:each="objMapEntry : ${objMap}" th:text="${objMapEntry['value']}"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: seems very complicated Isah! have you a sample example plz? thanks

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve is not simple, there's no simple way around it.
All you have to do is convert your list of objects to list of maps, then this table above will display that list of maps. For converting java objects to Maps, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739689/how-to-convert-a-java-object-bean-to-key-value-pairs-and-vice-versa